# Why isn't onPress calling the function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Entirely new to React Native. The problem isn't with the actual logic of the code. Tested it and it worked in a browser. Could it be with where code logic is placed inside render()? App doesn't render at all with it outside render(). Or is it because of where this.setState is?

[More Details. A lot more details. More Details. A lot more details. More Details. A lot more details. More Details. A lot more details. More Details. A lot more details. More Details. A lot more details. More Details. A lot more details. More Details. A lot more details. More Details. A lot more details.]

```
import React from 'react';
import type {Node} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';




class App extends React.Component{


constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state= {text: 'Lorem Ipsum admoniso'}
}



render() {


  // dataset for username 


const alpha= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

const num= ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'];


var counter = 0;
var Username;

// determine random length of the username

function UNlength() {
var UNlength = Math.random() *10;
UNlength = UNlength.toFixed(0);
if (UNlength == 0){UNlength = 1}
else {UNlength = UNlength};
return UNlength;}

var varUNlength = UNlength();
// function GenUsernameFn(){

// JS LOGICCCCCC

function UsernameFn(){


// 

  if (arguments.length == 0) {

// generate random nums as pickers

var PickerN = Math.random() * 10;
PickerN = PickerN.toFixed(0);


var PickerA = Math.random() * 26;
PickerA = PickerA.toFixed(0);

var PickerG = Math.random() * 10;
PickerG = PickerG.toFixed(0);



// Pickers for the first character in "Username"

var PickerUN = Math.random() * 10;
PickerUN = PickerUN.toFixed(0);

var PickerUA = Math.random() * 26;
PickerUA = PickerUA.toFixed(0);

var PickerUG = Math.random() * 10;
PickerUG = PickerUG.toFixed(0);


// choose randomly btw num and alpha. If Math.random 
// is an even num, option = alpha. If odd num, option = num

if (PickerG % 2 == 0) {var Chosen = num[PickerN];} else {var Chosen = alpha[PickerA];}

if (PickerUG % 2 == 0) { Username = num[PickerUN];} else { Username = alpha[PickerUA];}



//append each new choice to a string of previous choices
//when string = UNlength <= 10 chosen ranbdomly above, stop recursion.

// 'Username' declaration outside scope to allow loop access

Username = String(Username) + String(Chosen);
while (Username.length < varUNlength){UsernameFn(Username);}
}

else {
// algo for if Username is pre-defined 
// Pickers too

var PickerPN = Math.random() * 10;
PickerPN = PickerPN.toFixed(0);

var PickerPA = Math.random() * 26;
PickerPA = PickerPA.toFixed(0);

var PickerPG = Math.random() * 10;
PickerPG = PickerPG.toFixed(0);


if (PickerPG % 2 == 0) {var PickedNA =num[PickerPN];} else {var PickedNA = alpha[PickerPA];}

Username = String(Username) + String(PickedNA);
}

 while (Username.length < varUNlength){UsernameFn(Username);}
function Output(){
this.setState({text: {Username} });

}

} 


// actual react native

return (

    <View>

    <Text style={styles.TextCSS}>
{this.state.text}
    </Text>

<Button
  onPress={()=> UsernameFn() } 
  title="Click"
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>  



    </View>
)
}  

}
```

Comment: Please remove comments that are not useful to the question (for example the Section component)

Comment: @SamiElk change made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function Output is never called so you are never changing the state.
Also in you should write `this.setState({text: Username })` instead of `this.setState({text: {Username} })`.

To fix your issue you should write a if statement instead of a function like this:

```
if (Username.length >= varUNlength) {
    that.setState({ text: Username });
}
```

I wrote `that` instead of this because here `this` refers to the function UsernameFn instead of the App class component.

At the beginning of your render method you will need to add: `const that = this;` to make it work.

However your Class component still has multiple issues. Namely the functions should be class methods and not in the render method.

May I suggest a few optimizations:

1. Refactor all the pickers to 2 helper functions in a `helpers/getRandom.js` file like so:

```
const getRandomLetter = () => {
    const characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    const letterNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
    return characters[letterNumber];
};

const getRandomNumber = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
};

export { getRandomLetter, getRandomNumber };
```

2. Create 2 Class methods : `getRandomUsernameLength` and `getRandomUsername` and keep your render method lean:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { getRandomLetter, getRandomNumber } from './helpers/getRandom';
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: 'Lorem Ipsum admoniso' };
    }
    getRandomUsernameLength = () => {
        let UNlength = Math.random() * 10;
        UNlength = UNlength.toFixed(0);
        if (UNlength == 0) {
            UNlength = 1;
        } else {
            UNlength = UNlength;
        }
        return +UNlength;
    };

    getRandomUsername = () => {
        let username = '';
        const usernameLength = this.getRandomUsernameLength();
        while (username.length <= usernameLength) {
            const shouldBeLetter = Math.random() > 0.5;
            if (shouldBeLetter) {
                username += getRandomLetter();
            } else {
                username += getRandomNumber().toString();
            }
        }
        this.setState({ text: username });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.TextCSS}>{this.state.text}</Text>

                <Button
                    onPress={this.getRandomUsername}
                    title="Click"
                    color="#841584"
                    accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    TextCSS: {
        fontSize: 20,
    },
});
export default App;
```

Comment: impressive. Thanks so much. If I could bother you once more: how could I do what I asked about doing here? ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/69844251/17328947)?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that, the comments that were made already give all of the informations I could give you.

Comment: When you consider your issues completely fixed and you're not waiting for any more answers, don't forget to accept the answer you find the most comprehensive.